# Is it possible to remove "#" from the url using state provider

Tags: angularjs

Found this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/SDOcGS?p=preview on github which shows the basic working of State Provider which has Route 1 and Route 2 which display two views ViewA and ViewB respectively. I am trying to remove "#" from the url's of Route 1 and Route 2. Tried to use location provider to enable html 5 mode( $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)), but did not work. Is it possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` is exactly what you need.  Just make sure you're passing `$locationProvider` into your app config like you did for `$stateProvider`:

```
myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $locationProvider)
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/VF3fqnXgVKbo6cJA7xa9?p=preview

If you wanted to check browser support for the html5 history API:

```
if(window.history && window.history.pushState){
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}
```

Comment: Still not getting the needed result. On my local I deployed the above Plunker to the Apache server so that the url are more clearer in the browser. Now what I see happening is below: Without the location provider the url's are http://localhost:8080/StateProviderTest/#/route1 http://localhost:8080/StateProviderTest/#/route2 .Now when I add the location Provider these url change to: http://localhost:8080/route1 and http://localhost:8080/route2 Whereas the expectation is http://localhost:8080/StateProviderTest/route1                          http://localhost:8080/StateProviderTest/route2

Comment: Then change the `url` parameter of the state to `url: "/StateProviderTest/route1"` or whatever route you want pushed, and it will work.

Comment: Here's an updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/AsF0xbMFZhR0GZJilFfP?p=preview P.S. In the top right of the plunker result there's a blue full screen button. If you click it, it will open a full window of the plunker result and you can see the urls as they change.